# How to select/open a page available under a Multipage (Userform) using VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to prompt a message to a user to select at least one checkbox available under each Page's (Multipage option) on a Userform and navigate him to that page to select the checkbox

**Code**

```
'this will check whether any checkbox selected, if not it will prompt to select any one
If UF1_Revenue_Location_Role_Srch.Revenue_Loc_CheckBox1.Value = True And Not _
    (UF2_Revenue_DailyRate.MultiPage1.Page1.Revenue_Ind_CheckBox1.Value = True _
    Or UF2_Revenue_DailyRate.MultiPage1.Page1.Revenue_Ind_CheckBox2.Value = True _
    Or UF2_Revenue_DailyRate.MultiPage1.Page1.Revenue_Ind_CheckBox3.Value = True _
    Or UF2_Revenue_DailyRate.MultiPage1.Page1.Revenue_Ind_CheckBox4.Value = True _
    Or UF2_Revenue_DailyRate.MultiPage1.Page1.Revenue_Ind_CheckBox5.Value = True) Then
MsgBox "To Proceed: Kindly select atleast one Designation under Location India"
UF2_Revenue_DailyRate.MultiPage1.Page1.Show
    Call UserForm_Initialize

Else

 If UF1_Revenue_Location_Role_Srch.Revenue_Loc_CheckBox2.Value = True And Not _
    (UF2_Revenue_DailyRate.MultiPage1.Page2.Revenue_Ger_CheckBox1.Value = True _
    Or UF2_Revenue_DailyRate.MultiPage1.Page2.Revenue_Ger_CheckBox2.Value = True _
    Or UF2_Revenue_DailyRate.MultiPage1.Page2.Revenue_Ger_CheckBox3.Value = True _
    Or UF2_Revenue_DailyRate.MultiPage1.Page2.Revenue_Ger_CheckBox4.Value = True _
    Or UF2_Revenue_DailyRate.MultiPage1.Page2.Revenue_Ger_CheckBox5.Value = True) Then
MsgBox "To Proceed: Kindly select atleast one Designation under Location Germany"
UF2_Revenue_DailyRate.MultiPage1.Page2.Select
    Call UserForm_Initialize
```

On above code, I try to open the page using select option and Show option

```
UF2_Revenue_DailyRate.MultiPage1.Page1.Show
UF2_Revenue_DailyRate.MultiPage1.Page2.Select
```

but none of them really works.

Is there any other way to open this page to the user so that they can easily select the checkbox from it instead of selecting the page one by one?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the Attribute `Value` of your Multipage:

```
UF2_Revenue_DailyRate.MultiPage1.Value = 0 'Page1
UF2_Revenue_DailyRate.MultiPage1.Value = 1 'Page2
```

Remember that it starts with `0`

Comment: Thanks @sporc, but how to select it ??

Comment: What do you mean with select? Changing the value programmatically will directly display the associated multipage. E.g. changing the value to `2` will show/select the multipage 3 in the userform

Comment: thank you @sporc, in fact, I got a bit confused on this... now it worked.... thanks a lot